# Insertion Sort, 4 Dimensional Arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

As part of an assignment, I am supposed to write a method that uses insertion sort to sort the 3D arrays inside a 4D array based on the number of doubles inside each 3D array.

I have this so far for the method, but it seems to only work if the smallest 3D array is **not** in the last position (`four[2]`, where for `four` is a 4D array with 3 elements).

```
public static void sort4DArray(double[][][][] list) {
    int x;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        double[][][] currentElement = list[i];
        //shifts the 3D arrays   
        for (x = i - 1; x >= 0 && count(list,x) > count(list,i); x--) {
            list[x + 1] = list[x];
        } 
        //inserts the 3D array to its new position
        list[x + 1] = currentElement;
    }
}
```

Note that within this method I use another method "count" that counts how many doubles are inside a given 3D array. I'll leave the code below for reference:

```
public static int count(double[][][][] list, int x) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j=0; j < list[x].length; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k < list[x][j].length; k++){
            count += list[x][j][k].length;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here is two sample outputs, the first one is right the second one is incorrect:
The arrays are printed in parenthetical format, I hope it is easy to understand.

The arrays within the array are of random length (ragged), and the doubles within are also randomly generated.

```
{
    {
        {{0.5, 3.6, 8.9, }} 
        {{26.7, 20.5, 4.7, }} 
        {{15.3, }} 
    }, 
    {
        {{25.5, }} 
    }, 
    {
        {{15.8, 5.8, 0.2, }{12.7, }} 
        {{25.8, }} 
    }, 
}

After Sort:
{
    {
        {{25.5, }} 
    }, 
    {
        {{0.2, 5.8, 15.8, }{12.7, }} 
        {{25.8, }} 
    }, 
    {
        {{0.5, 3.6, 8.9, }} 
        {{4.7, 20.5, 26.7, }} 
        {{15.3, }} 
    }, 
}
```

This is the second output. Note that the smallest 3D array is last in the first print:

```
{
    {
        {{22.4, }{29.8, }{5.5, }} 
        {{10.2, 6.4, }} 
    }, 
    {
        {{13.4, }{24.0, }{3.5, 6.0, }} 
        {{14.1, 8.5, }{5.6, 14.3, }{22.1, }} 
    }, 
    {
        {{20.1, }} 
    }, 
}

After Sort:
{
    {
        {{22.4, }{29.8, }{5.5, }} 
        {{6.4, 10.2, }} 
    }, 
    {
        {{20.1, }} 
    }, 
    {
        {{13.4, }{24.0, }{3.5, 6.0, }} 
        {{8.5, 14.1, }{5.6, 14.3, }{22.1, }} 
    }, 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would simplify your `count()` function to take one less dimension:

```
public static int count(double[][][] list) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j=0; j < list.length; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k < list[j].length; k++){
            count += list[j][k].length;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

With this, we replace your old calls to `count(list, x)` with new calls to `count(list[x])`.

As for the insertion sort, the fix is simple: Change `count(list[x]) > count(list[i])` to `count(list[x]) > count(currentElement)`. This is because `list[i]` gets overwritten by the `list[x + 1] = list[x]` logic at the first iteration of the inner loop you defined. (Note: I've verified this fixed algorithm with millions of randomized test cases.)